# Azure QnA Bot ServiceError: CreateAppOnlySteps

Tags: azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

While following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/Quickstarts/create-publish-knowledge-base#create-a-bot), the step that creates the web app bot in Azure results in an error. After clicking `Create Bot` in QnA Maker, accepting all of the default values in the new Azure window, and clicking the `Create` button to create the web app bot, the following error is printed:

> ServiceError: CreateAppOnlySteps

Clicking on the error opens a panel on the right, but the panel is empty with no further detail. What does this error mean, and why won't Azure create the web app bot?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and still didn't find the solution.

Comment: do you get an additional error on the dev console? Also, are you able to just log into azure and create a bot using the Web App Bot option?

Comment: Have not tried. How can a Web App Bot be connected to the Q&A Maker? I was choosing the `Create Bot` option directly within the Q&A Maker dashboard.

Comment: Usually it's related to permissions on your account.  Make sure you have the Application Administrator role.

Comment: Try this solution mentioned over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698893/2077750

Comment: @crayden I suggested trying on Azure as many are experiencing the same error due to permission issues. You will need to check if you have the necessary role permissions as mentioned in the above link.