# Not able to create a Web App Bot through Azure portal, getting ServiceError: CreateAppOnlySteps

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I am trying to create a Web App Bot in Azure, getting error **ServiceError: CreateAppOnlySteps**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ayNW.png

Comment: are you still having issues? is it only when you create a basic bot or is it the same when you try creating an echo bot?

Comment: Make sure you have the Application Administrator role on your account.

Comment: Role was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like error : **ServiceError: CreateAppOnlySteps** is due to insufficient permissions.

Can you check, do you have access to create an APP Registration under Azure Active Directory.

If yes, follow below link and create an APP & Secret using below link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-bot-framework-faq?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#app-registration

Once you are done with App Registration, copy the APP Id, Secret and apply that during BOT Registration like below :

[image: Adding APP & Secret during bot registration]

Try the above steps, it may work

Thanks !!!